# hcitool lescan returns an I/O error on Manjaro

Tags: bluetooth, manjaro, hci, arch

I'm trying to connect MX Master 3 to my computer.

OS: Manjaro 21.2.1 Qonos 
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.10.89-1-MANJARO 
Computer: Dell XPS 7390

I tried:

```
sudo hcitool lescan
```

which gives:

```
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
```

`rfkill list all` gives:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

and `hcitool dev` gives:

```
Devices:
        hci0    84:1B:77:B4:B4:D1
```

Things I have already tried:

```
hciconfig hci0 down
hciconfig hci0 up
```

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl restart dbus.service
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add SOLVED to the title or edit a solution into  the question. If you've solved the problem and want to share it, do so properly by writing an answer provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, a site about programming problems, algorithms and software development tools. This question is better suited for https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Inside `bluetoothctl`:
`menu scan`
`tranport le`
`back`
`scan on`
Resolved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `bluetoothctl`:

```
menu scan
transport le
back
scan on
```

This resolved the problem.